# How do I see that for a matrix $A \in \text {Mat}_{m \times n}(\mathbb R)$ the following holds: $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} A(x-x_0) = 0?$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

How do I see that for a matrix $A \in \text {Mat}_{m \times n}(\mathbb R)$ the following holds: $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} A(x-x_0) = 0?$

I see that  $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} A(x)-A(x_0) = (\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} A(x)) - A(x_0)$.

Writing $\sum_{j = 1}^n a_{i,j}x_j$ for the $i$'th coordinate of $A(x)$, can I use this to prove the above ?

Comment: Since $A(x_0+h)=A(x_0)+A(h)$ it is enough to prove that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\,A(h)=0$.

Comment: If the limit is defined using a certain norm, note that on a finite dimensional vector space, all norms are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\|\cdot\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{\mathbb{R}^m}$ be a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and on $\mathbb{R}^m$ respectively. We wish to see
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} A(x-x_0) = 0 \in \mathbb{R}^m$$
in the norms, that is
$$\|A(x-x_0)\|_{\mathbb{R}^m} = \|A(x-x_0) - 0\|_{\mathbb{R}^m} \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } \|x - x_0\|_{\mathbb{R}^n} \rightarrow 0$$

---

Proof: Since $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are finite dimensional vector spaces, all norms on such spaces are equivalent. In particular, $\|\cdot\|_{\mathbb{R}^m}$ is equivalent to $\|\cdot\|_2$ (or any induced norm) in $\mathbb{R}^m$, that is, there exists $c_1 > 0$ such that
$$\|y\|_{\mathbb{R}^m} \leq c_1\|y\|_2 \text{ for } y \in \mathbb{R}^m$$
Similarly, there exists $c_2 > 0$ such that
$$\|x\|_2 \leq c_2\|x\|_{\mathbb{R}^n} \text{ for } x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$
Using this we have
$$0 \leq \|A(x-x_0)\|_{\mathbb{R}^m} \leq c_1\|A(x-x_0)\|_2 \leq c_1\|A\|_2\|x-x_0\|_2 \leq c_1c_2\|A\|_2\|x-x_0\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}$$
Using squeeze theorem we have
$$\|A(x-x_0)\|_{\mathbb{R}^m} \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } \|x - x_0\|_{\mathbb{R}^n} \rightarrow 0$$

Comment: Very detailed and very informative. Thank you !